# How to add/remove class to checkbox elements in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue.js component, I'd like to add a background color to any checkbox that is clicked:

```
<div class="langs-container">

    <div class="lang">
        <input type="checkbox"   value="English"   class="mycheckbox" v-model="languages">
        English
    </div>
    <div class="lang">
        <input type="checkbox"   value="French"   class="mycheckbox" v-model="languages">
        French
    </div>

</div>
```

So let's say we want to add `green` to each checkbox that is active (ticked) and remove it when unticked:

```
.green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

What's the idomatic way to achieve this?

Update: `languages` is an array, so I can not define `English` and `French` as false by default.

Comment: use class binding https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, I saw that page but can not apply it to this particular  case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each checkbox a `v-model` which is used for class binding.

Distinguish the two checkboxes by using an object for the `input` as `v-model`:

`<input v-model="languages.english"...>`

Use class binding based on that:

`<div class="lang" :class="{ 'green': languages.english }">`

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments, here is a solution for `languages` as array (instead of object), which is not as "clean" anymore:

You need an additional method to return `true` or `false` based on the checked values.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      languages: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isChecked(value) {
     return this.languages.includes(value)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="langs-container">

    <div class="lang" :class="{ 'green': isChecked('English') }">
      <input type="checkbox" value="English" class="mycheckbox" v-model="languages"> English
    </div>
    <div class="lang" :class="{ 'green': isChecked('French') }">
      <input type="checkbox" value="French" class="mycheckbox" v-model="languages"> French
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the issue is that in my case, `languages` is expected to be an array, not an object. So this solution is not applicable, at least in present shape.

Comment: @Babr Updated my answer.